HTTP GET Callback Requests Delayed or Not Reaching AWS ECS from Third-Party Service
I’m running an application on AWS Elastic Container Service (ECS) with a backend server that exposes a GET endpoint to receive callbacks from a third-party service (outside of our VPC). The third party has confirmed that they are sending the requests, and they’ve provided logs showing correct timestamps when the requests were made.
Problem:

When testing the callback using Postman, everything works perfectly, and the requests reach the server instantly.
However, the requests sent by the third party either arrive with a significant delay (e.g., 12+ hours) or don’t arrive at all.
So far, only one request has successfully reached the server after a full day delay.

Setup:

AWS ECS container.
GET endpoint is exposed and works when tested with tools like Postman.
Third-party service is sending GET requests with data to this endpoint.
The application logs every request and inserts relevant data into MongoDB, but we are not seeing the requests from the third party in the logs.

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Postman requests successfully hit the server, so the endpoint appears to be functional.
Received logs from third-party service confirming requests sent successfully.

Questions:

What could cause GET requests from a third party to be delayed or lost when hitting an AWS ECS endpoint, while Postman requests work as expected?
Are there any AWS-specific configurations (e.g., networking, security groups, load balancing) that might explain why requests from an external service are not consistently reaching the server?
Could this be related to DNS resolution or caching issues on their side?
What additional troubleshooting steps should I take to ensure that the third-party requests are received in a timely manner?

Disclaimer: I have very little experience with AWS environment
Thanks in advance

There is nothing in AWS that would delay that request. Amazon would have to be storing that HTTP request, and just holding onto it for hours, before finally forwarding it on. There is nothing in AWS that would do such a thing.  If you have a CDN like CloudFront in front of your service, it could be returning a cached response to the third-party instead of forwarding the request to your server, but that wouldn't result in a delay, just a request never making it to your server. If you want to add more logging on your side to debug this, you should enable access logs on the load balancer.
